# Set so that LibreOffice Impress will go straight into show slide mode

Tags: libreoffice

When I start my libre office presentation, I would like it to go automatically into slide show mode. How can I do so?

[With Microsoft Office you can do this by renaming a presentation to .pps (from .ppt) or .ppsx (from .pptx)]

Comment: As far as I know, Impress does not support that feature. You can only save a presentation as a .odp(presentation) and .otp(template). You can try to visit this [site](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10714) and this [site](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=87696) for a possible workaround.

Comment: Impress does have the option to "Save As" PowerPoint (autoplay) PPS.  You can select from the "All Formats" drop-down selection when saving the file

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this using terminal

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run following command

```
libreoffice --show yourfilename.ppt
```

I wanted to run a presentation looping on a notice board but for some odd reasons, pps files were inserting a pause of 10 seconds between last and first slides even if I set the relevant option to 0 sec, whereas odp was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about LibreOffice, but I know its 'brother' OpenOffice. 
In Open Office Impress, if you right-click the file name, you will see the option 'Show'. Selecting that will open the presentation directly in show mode.