# Running powerpoint slides from Ubuntu terminal in Windows 7 using VirtualBox

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

Does anybody know how I can run MS powerpoint slides from Ubuntu terminal (my host OS) in Windows 7 (my guest OS)- I think I should use .pps to run it automatically. What I'm doing now is:

```
VBoxManage --nologo guestcontrol "myWindows7" execute --image "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" --username my_username --password my_password -- start "Opening file..." "E:\My_presentation_slides.pps"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to to do this, and to my knowledge what you are doing should already work, but as an alternative, you can run `simpress /path/to/file.pps` and it should open the slideshow with LibreOffice and automatically play it.

See also this question: [Set so that LibreOffice Impress will go straight into show slide mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/177587/set-so-that-libreoffice-impress-will-go-straight-into-show-slide-mode)

Comment: Actually I have to open it with MS office. If I delete the path at the end in the arguments it launches the powerpng.exe but when I give the path It won't work. It will say PowerPoint can't read C:\mypath and in the details it says it has problems with the antivirus but I have shut it down and also windows firewalls. I have also tried to put the file in a folder in the root of C drive but it won't work!

Comment: What is the particular reason for why you **have** to run it with MS Office?

Comment: It's part of my project!

Comment: @makman being vague is not helpful here. I'm not asking why just because I can. If it's really just a personal choice, then I and others are less likely (and not really obligated) to go the extra mile. So, if you have a real and serious reason, please state it. Otherwise, I'll put my efforts elsewhere.